# Properties of SharePoint framework web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

How to get all the associated properties of Web part in SharePoint framework?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Let's say we want to get the instanceId of the spfx web part, we can simply get it by "this.context.instanceId". Here is list of some other properties the intelisense shown:

[image]